# Use JList in JComboBox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, jlist, defaultlistmodel

I have a JList which is of DefaultListModel. I am not trying to create a JComboBox which should display as its the elements, the elements in the JList.

What is the best way to achieve this ?
Thank you.

My code:

```
DefaultListModel<String> listModelTopic = new DefaultListModel<>();
//create the list
listTopic = new JList<>(listModelTopic);
//create comboBox
JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
comboBox.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(topicList.getModel());
```

Error: The constructor DefaultComboBoxModel(ListModel) is undefined

Comment: Please add the error information to provider the solution.

Comment: *"I am unable to solve the type-cast errors."* Fixing basic compilation errors is something a programmer should figure out before attempting GUIs. *"Can anyone present a snippet to do the same ?"* SO is not a help desk, or a code generation machine. Voting to close.

Comment: @AndrewThompson: I apologize for my choice of words in the question. I think my mistake however was only to not present the error. The intention of the question itself is not useless. If I may suggest, edit the question instead of closing it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `copyInto` on `DefaultListModel` to copy all the values to an array.

```
 String[] lstArray = new String[listModelTopic.getSize];
 listModelTopic.copyInto(lstArray );
```

Then create `DefaultComboBoxModel` using this array.

```
DefaultComboBoxModel comboModel = new DefaultComboBoxModel(lstArray );
 JComboBox comboBox = new JComboBox();
 comboBox.setModel(comboModel );
```

Hope this helps!